# How to access data from database and make an option value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name from room");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$firstValue="";
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    if($firstValue==""){ 
        $firstValue=$data['name'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST["occupant"])and trim($_POST["choice"])==$data['name']){
        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$data['name'].'" >'.$data['name'];
        echo '</option>';
    }else
        {
         echo '<option value="'.$data['name'].'" >'.$data['name'];
         echo '</option>';
         }
    }
```

What i want here is to show all data from my database but when i open it in browser shows only the second data down to the last data. And i wonder why the first data is missing.
Can anybody knows my mistake here?

Comment: Also, note, you should switch to the mysqli_ or PDO extension as the mysql_ extension is going to be deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. It is an easy change and good to do it as you start out rather than later on. :-)

Comment: I don't really follow what 'second data' is. You mean you want to skip the first record altogether? Just filter it out in your SQL. use the LIMIT clause: LIMIT 999, 1. Or use WHERE id > 1.

Comment: how to switch to mysqli? @Richard Testani, i don't want to skip the first, what i want is to show all data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the first:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

It is popping the first record off of your result set.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name from room");
$firstValue="";
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: i did this many times but still the first data is missing.. how to set off?

Comment: I did. I even showed you how to fix it. What part of my answer do you not understand that I might need to clarify for you?

Comment: do i have to erase this block of code? 
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what you need to do.